# Flip d3js svg line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to flip the line so that the higher value goes up and the lower value goes down. I tried to use `scale(1,-1)` but it doesn't output anything. Please see my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="paths"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var canvas = d3.select(".paths").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500);

    var data = [
      {x:10, y:200},
      {x:30, y:170},
      {x:50, y:70},
      {x:70, y:140},
      {x:90, y:150},
      {x:110, y:120},
      {x:130, y:150},
      {x:150, y:140},
      {x:170, y:110}
    ];

    var group = canvas.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "scale(1,1)");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d){ return d.x })
      .y(function(d){ return d.y });


    group.selectAll("path")
      .data([data])
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);


  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/dayoxon/7/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a scale, which by the way will fix *another* problem you have: your data values should not be (or normally will not be) SVG coordinates.

This is a basic example of a linear scale:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 200])
    .range([height,0]);
```

Here, the domain goes from 0 to 200, which is the maximum in your data. Then, those values will be mapped to:

```
.range([height, 0])
```

Where `height` is the height of the SVG.

Finally, use the scale in the line generator:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d){ return d.x })
  .y(function(d){ return scale(d.y) });
```

Here is your code with that scale:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="paths"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var canvas = d3.select(".paths").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 300);

    var data = [
      {x:10, y:200},
      {x:30, y:170},
      {x:50, y:70},
      {x:70, y:140},
      {x:90, y:150},
      {x:110, y:120},
      {x:130, y:150},
      {x:150, y:140},
      {x:170, y:110}
    ];

    var group = canvas.append('g');
      
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 200])
      .range([300,0]);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d){ return d.x })
      .y(function(d){ return scale(d.y) });
    
    
    group.selectAll("path")
      .data([data])
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);


  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. so basically you reverse its base and top? using .range([height,0])

Comment: Yes. This is a good reading about scales: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales